# Elasticsearch to recommend book authors: how to limit maximum 3 books per author?

Tags: elasticsearch, recommendation-engine

I use Elasticsearch to recommend authors (my Elasticsearch documents represent books, with a title, a summary and a list of author ids).

The user queries my index with some text (e.g. `Georgia` or `Paris`) and I need to aggregate the score of individual books at the author level (meaning: recommand an author that writes about Paris).

I began with a simple aggregation, however, experimentally (cross-validation) it is best to stop aggregating the score of each users after maximum 4 books per user. This way, we do not have an author with 200 books that can "dominate" the results. Let me explain in pseudocode:

```
# the aggregated score of each author
Map<Author, Double>  author_scores = new Map()
# the number of books (hits) that contributed to each author
Map<Author, Integer> author_cnt = new Map()

# iterate ES query results
for Document doc in hits:

    # stop aggregating if more that 4 books from this author have already been found
    if (author_cnt.get(doc.author_id) < 4):
        author_scores.increment_by(doc.author_id, doc.score)
        author_cnt.increment_by(doc.author_id, 1)

the_result = author_scores.sort_map_by_value(reverse=true)
```

So far, I have implemented the above aggregation in custom application code, but I was wondering if it was possible to rewrite it using Elasticsearch's query DSL or `org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregator` interface.

Comment: Why do you want to stop after a count of 4? And what does it mean "stop"? You want ES not to use CPU/memory if it reaches 4 books?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I still don't understand why the limit on 4 books. If it's about the "domination" (through scoring) of results, I'm sure the scoring can be manipulated in a query accordingly. Custom function_score, if I remember well, can put a cap on scoring for a certain function. So, if you have a query where you're interested in 4 books only, this "4" will be considered a cap and no matter how much "scoring" a document will get, it will be topped at "4". Let me know if this is your intent and maybe share more of what you actually want to do (the whole story).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that you cannot do this with the features ES offers. The closest thing I could find about your requirement is ["top_hits" aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html). With this you perform your query, you aggregate on whatever you want and then you say you need only the top X hits ordered by a criteria.

For your particular scenario your query is a "match" for "Paris", the aggregation is on author id and then you tell ES to only return the first 3 books, ordered by score for each author. The good part is that ES will offer you the best three books for each particular author, ordered by relevance, and not all the books for each or none. The not-so-good part is that "top-hits" doesn't allow another sub-aggregation to  make possible a sum of scores only for those "top hits". In this case you would still need to compute the sum of scores for each author.

And a sample query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "Paris"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top-authors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author_ids"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_books_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "include": [
                "title"
              ]
            },
            "size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```